# How to enable Web NFC without origin trial?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, nfc, webnfc

Web NFC is a [W3C draft](https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/), and should theoretically be available in Chrome on Android with [Chrome Origin Trials](https://developers.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/236438980436951041) ([here is a demo](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/)). Unfortunately the [trial for Web NFC](https://developers.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/236438980436951041) was only running for Chrome 81 to 83 (although [caniuse.com suggest differently](https://caniuse.com/webnfc)).

Question: can anyone explain how to get Web NFC enabled on a newer version of Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described at https://web.dev/nfc/#enabling-via-chrome:flags, to experiment with Web NFC on Android, enable the `#experimental-web-platform-features` flag in chrome://flags.